# RegEx for finding words with NOT ONLY ONE space between them

Tags: regex, perl, grep

I need help with a RegEx problem:

I want to find occurences of two known words ("foo" and "bar" for example), that have any white space other than EXACTLY ONE SPACE CHARACTER between them.

In the text that I have to grep, there may be spaces, tabs, CRs, LFs or any combination of them between the two words.

In RegEx words:
I need one regular expression that matches `"foo[ \t\n\r]+bar"` but does NOT match `"foo bar"`.

Everything I've tried so far either missed some combinations or also matched the single-space-case which is the only one that should NOT match.

Thanks in advance for any solutions.

*EDIT: To clarify, I'm using Perl compatible RegEx here.*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could also use a negative lookahead:

```
foo(?! \b)\s+bar
```

If lookaheads are not supported you can write it explicitly:

```
foo(?:[^\S ]| \s)\s*bar
```

The expression `[^\S ]` includes a double negative and it might not be immediately obvious how this works. If you work it out the logic it means any whitespace apart from a space.

Comment: This seems to work. Interesting twist with the not-non-whitespace-thing. The lookahead is nice, too.

Comment: I think, I'll go with the lookahead. It's easier to remember and to read.

Answer (score 1):

You could use (assuming ERE, i.e. `grep -E`)

```
foo[:space:]{2,}bar
```

The syntax `x{min,}` means the pattern `x` must appear at least `min` times.

---

If by "other than EXACTLY ONE SPACE CHARACTER" you mean except the 0x20 space character, you need an alternation:

```
foo([\t\n\r]|[ \t\n\r]{2,})bar
```

Comment: Both of these miss the cases where there is a single tab, CR or LF beteen the words.

Comment: @Techpriester: The alternation solution should work, and is quite readable.

Comment: No, like some other posted solutions here, it misses the case when there is one single "\t" between the words.

Answer (score 0):

use [:space:]{2,}

{2,} means 2 or more

Comment: Nope. This misses "foo\tbar" for example.